# R - Função para gerar gráficos e alterar eixos

Tags: r, funções, ggplot2

Preciso exibir quatro gráficos, várias vezes em um relatório Rmarkdown.

Por isso, decidi criar uma função para plotar os gráficos. Ficou assim:

```r
gera_graficos <- function(base,var1,var2){

hist1 <- ggplot(sqrt(base), aes(x=var1)) + geom_histogram() + labs(y = "Frequência") 
hist2 <- ggplot(sqrt(base), aes(x=var2)) + geom_histogram() + labs(y = "Frequência")

boxp1 <- ggplot(sqrt(base), aes(x=var1)) + geom_boxplot() + coord_flip()  +  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(),axis.ticks = element_blank())
boxp2 <- ggplot(sqrt(base), aes(x=var2)) + geom_boxplot() + coord_flip()  +  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(),axis.ticks = element_blank())
boxplot <- ggarrange(boxp1,boxp2, ncol = 2, nrow = 1)

corr <- ggplot(sqrt(base), aes(x=var1,y=var2)) + geom_point()

graficos_combinados <- ggarrange(hist1,boxplot,corr,hist2, ncol = 2, nrow = 2)

plot(graficos_combinados)

}

gera_graficos(Disponibilidade,Disponibilidade$Caixa,Disponibilidade$Dep_Banc)
```

Porém, o resultado está sendo esse:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Preciso que:**

**1)** Ao invés de "var1" e "var2" apareça o nome da variável;

**2)** A valor dos eixos não apareçam em notação, mas em valor normalizado pelo sqrt()

**3)** O modo como criei a função está certo? Se eu por:

```
gera_graficos(Disponibilidade,Caixa,Dep_Banc)
```

Não funciona.

Exemplo do resultado que preciso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você pode usar um `{{ }}` que resolve a maioria dos seus problemas.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggpubr)

dados_teste <- select(diamonds, carat, price)

gera_graficos <- function(base,var1,var2){

  hist1 <- ggplot(sqrt(base), aes(x={{ var1 }})) + geom_histogram() + labs(y = "Frequência") 
  hist2 <- ggplot(sqrt(base), aes(x={{ var2 }})) + geom_histogram() + labs(y = "Frequência")

  boxp1 <- ggplot(sqrt(base), aes(x={{ var1 }})) + geom_boxplot() + coord_flip()  +  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(),axis.ticks = element_blank())
  boxp2 <- ggplot(sqrt(base), aes(x={{ var2 }})) + geom_boxplot() + coord_flip()  +  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(),axis.ticks = element_blank())
  boxplot <- ggarrange(boxp1,boxp2, ncol = 2, nrow = 1)

  corr <- ggplot(sqrt(base), aes(x={{ var1 }},y={{ var2 }})) + geom_point()

  graficos_combinados <- ggarrange(hist1,boxplot,corr,hist2, ncol = 2, nrow = 2)

  plot(graficos_combinados)

}

gera_graficos(dados_teste, carat, price)
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Muito obrigado! Resolveu!